# Python import local dataset in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working on image classification in tensorflow. I am at the point of loading a local dataset from my project directory into my python file. I am following the tensorflow docs (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification), and when I reach the point of adding data, the docs import the data from the internet using a google dataset. They use

```
dataset_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz"
```

and then

```
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('flower_photos', origin=dataset_url, untar=True)
```

How would I do these same thing with a local directory called DataSet?

Comment: Is the data already pre-processed? This section of this tutorial might be helpful: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images#load_using_keraspreprocessing

Answer (score 2):

`get_file` will download only if not existed. So you can set `fname` to a local file, and set `origin = ''` like:

```
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file(os.path.abspath('flower_photos'), origin='', untar=True)
```

`os.path.abspath` is needed since `keras` search `cache_dir` for the file by default.

And since `untar` is deprecated, you may better use `extract` instead like:

```
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file(os.path.abspath('flower_photos.tar.gz'), origin='', extract=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

suppose that your DataSet contains subfolders that contain image.png.

```
 import pathlib

data_dir = pathlib.Path('path/to/your/DataSet_folder')

list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(data_dir/'*/*.png'))
```

list_ds contains all paths to your images.